# Error when run app (Maven) (Intellj Idea)

Tags: macos, maven, gwt, java-8

I have a problem when run app(Maven,GWT), the console shows me:

```
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @loader_path/. in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java being ignored in restricted program because of @loader_path
2018-09-11 15:07:48.631 java[6257:272434] The application with bundle ID net.java.openjdk.cmd is running setugid(), which is not allowed.
```

even in the terminal with `java -version`

```
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @loader_path/. in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java being ignored in restricted program because of @loader_path
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: are you using open jdk?

Comment: hi @SannTran, fix it :) , just install a new jdk